# Enumerate substitutions with sed or awk

Tags: vim, sed, awk, enumeration, substitution

Given the plain text file with lines

```
bli foo bla
 abc
 dfg
bli foo bla
 hik
 lmn
```

what sed or awk magic transforms it to

```
bli foo_01 bla
 abc
 dfg
bli foo_02 bla
 hik
 lmn
```

so that every occurence of 'foo' is replaced by 'foo_[occurence number]'.

Comment: Michael, More explanation of the requirements, and especially the input format is required for anyone to attempt to answer this  question meaninfully... I presume you've dummied up what is intended to be a simplified but representative sample of a real-world file... What is that file? a log file? a mysql log file? Just a guess. Cheers. Keith.

Comment: actually it's a java source file and the transformation is used to make the method names unique

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the solutions, I modified the question a bit, adding some noise around the foo

Comment: Yeah, ain't it funny how programmers resort to perl, awk, nawk, ed, sed, and/or tr when they just want to get something done ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way to express radoulov's answer

```
awk '/foo/ {sub(/foo/, "&_" sprintf("%02d",++c))} 1' infile
```

You should take care that you don't match "foobar" while looking for "foo":

```
gawk '/\<foo\>/ {sub(/\<foo\>/, "&_" sprintf("%02d",++c))} 1'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '!/foo/||sub(/foo/,"&_"++_)' infile
```

Use *gawk*, *nawk* or */usr/xpg4/bin/awk* on *Solaris*.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't what you require, but it might give some ideas in the right direction.

```
Administrator@snadbox3 ~
$ cd c:/tmp

Administrator@snadbox3 /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ cat <<-eof >foo.txt
> foo
>  abc
>  dfg
> foo
>  hik
>  lmn
> eof

Administrator@snadbox3 /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ awk '/^foo$/{++fooCount; print($0 "_" fooCount);} /^ /{print}' foo.txt
foo_1
 abc
 dfg
foo_2
 hik
 lmn
```

---

**EDIT:**

I'm a day late and a penny short, again ;-(

---

**EDIT2:**

Character encodings is another thing to lookout for... Java source code isn't necessarily in the systems default encoding... it's quit UTF-8 encoded, to allow for any embedded "higher order entities" ;-) Many *nix utilities still aren't charset-aware.